# How to position a div as a block at the bottom of the HTML5 video player?

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-video

I want to create my own UI for the HTML5 Video Player. But I cannot get the first step right. I want to position a div where the default HTML5 Video Player controls are. I don't know how to position the `controls` div there. Please Help Me.

My code:

```css
#video_player {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}

#controls {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100px;
  background-color: #55b2ff;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="video_player_box">
    <video video-player id="video_player" src="http://dash.akamaized.net/akamai/bbb/bbb_1280x720_60fps_6000k.mp4" controls></video>
    <div id="controls"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if i understood right, try it
`#controls { 
    position: relative;
    top: -38px;
}`

Comment: How can I allow the div to stay with full screen mode?

Comment: im not see an button for make it full screen, to check it, on player i mean.

Comment: I have no idea why the full screen button is not there but it is being shown on my website.

Comment: It seems like there is a chrome bug with the full screen mode. I cant turn in on in your video either.

Comment: Damn. I don't know how I can allow the full screen mode to appear

Comment: I'm using google chrome and on my website, the video player shows the full screen button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The child should have `position: absolute` relative to the parent.

### Ps: You should use classes for styling.

```css
#video_player {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}

#controls {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 100px;
    background-color:#55b2ff;
}

.video_player_container {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="video_player_container">
        <video video-player id="video_player" src="http://dash.akamaized.net/akamai/bbb/bbb_1280x720_60fps_6000k.mp4" controls></video>
        <div id="controls"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```